# Как лучше написать метод?

Tags: php, code-style, css

Есть функция getValue(), которая берет массив ключей и значений из функции getArray() и возвращает value для key = $foo (если есть).

```
function getArray() {
  // Возвращается массив типа:
  // Array ( 
  //   [0] => Array ( [key] => a [value] => а ) 
  //   [1] => Array ( [key] => b [value] => б ) 
  //   [2] => Array ( [key] => c [value] => в ) 
  // ) 
}

function getValue( $foo ) {
  $arr = array();
  foreach(getArray() as $i) {
      $arr[$i['key']] = $i['value'];    
  }

  if ( isset( $arr[$foo] ) )
    return $arr[$foo];
  else
    return 'Nope';
}
```

Этот код работает, но визуально не нравится ни разу. Есть ли способ упростить или улучшить функцию getValue?

Пока нашел только такое решение:

```
function getValue( $foo ) {
  foreach(getArray() as $i) {
    if ($i['key'] == $foo)
      return $i['value'];
  }
  return 'Nope';
}
```

Comment: А чем не устраивает второй вариант? Вполне оптимальное решение. Проход по массиву делается ровно до искомого элемента.

Comment: Интересно, какие еще есть варианты.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getValue($foo){
     if(array_key_exist($foo, $arr)){
         return $arr[$foo]
     }else{
         return null;
     }
}
```

Comment: Точно и возвращать надо null в случае неудачи. Только еще второй параметр в array_key_exist надо, где искать то :)

Comment: Массив на входе многомерный. array_key_exist() требует два параметра. Хорошо, как замена блока

    if ( isset( $arr[$foo] ) )
      return $arr[$foo];
    else
      return 'Nope';

Comment: @Khvorostin, почему не заменить 
<pre><code>// Возвращается массив типа:
// Array ( 
//   [0] => Array ( [key] => a [value] => а ) 
//   [1] => Array ( [key] => b [value] => б ) 
//   [2] => Array ( [key] => c [value] => в ) 
// ) 
</code></pre>
на
<pre><code>// Возвращается массив типа:
// Array ( 
//   [0] => Array ( 'a' => 'а' ) 
//   [1] => Array ( 'b' => 'б' ) 
//   [2] => Array ( 'c' => 'в' ) 
// )</code></pre>
?

Comment: @stck Потому что это данные из БД. Если есть вариант запроса к БД, когда возвращается не многомерный массив, а простой, это сильно упросило бы мне задачу.

Comment: @Khvorostin, всегда есть варианты. Но для этого требуется посмотреть метод getValue()

Comment: @Khvorostin, Вы пытаетесь реализовать транслитерацию?